modprobe vboxguest fail
In my new installed Centos 9 stream, I try to install virtualbox guest addition and it fails with error:
sudo tail /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log

modprobe vboxguest fail


Here is my setup:
uname -r
5.14.0-467.el9.x86_64

and the kernel headers:
sudo yum list | grep kernel


And the status of the other dependencies:

The rebooting also does not help.
I cannot think of any other solution.
Please help.

Please don't post screenshots of console output. They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

@AdminBee, If the virtualbox guest addition was working, I would definitely post the full text too.
